# Returning a recursive function in ML

Tags: recursion, sml, ml

How can I return a recursive function in ML?

As far as I know recursive anonymous functions cannot be returned and only anonymous functions 
can be used as returning value(if the returning value is function...).

Comment: Can you rephrase the question or give an example? Why do you think that you cannot return a recursive function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this be the kind of example you are wondering about?

```
fun f n =
   let
      fun g k =
         if k = n then [] else k :: g (k-1)
   in
      g
   end
```

You can only make a recursive definition by naming it, but that's not a problem, because you can write a `let` expression anywhere.

**Update** to answer comment more specifically:

```
fun f g =
   let
      fun h 0 = g 0
        | h i = h (i-1) + g i
   in
      h
   end
```

(A more efficient implementation would make `h` tail-recursive.)

Comment: I am tying to implement a function f: (int->int) -> (int->int) that receives a function g as parameter and return h, where:                  h= $sum_{i=0}^{i}g(i)$                                                         I tried to use "let" and after a lot of trying still it doesn't work well.